# Crear archivos de texto y almacenar palabras

Tags: python, string, archivo, bucle-for, texto

Actualice mi idea, ahora quiero crear un archivo txt con la primera palabra de la oración y que dentro lleve la segunda palabra de la oración, seguido borre la primera palabra de la oración y se cree otro txt con la nueva primera palabra y guarde nuevamente la palabra que le sigue y así hasta terminar con una oración.

Ejemplo:

```
(Yo soy Lola.)

Yo.txt=soy
soy.txt=Lola.
Lola..txt=(no habra nada porque la oración concluyo)
```

Si la segunda oración que venga tiene palabras que han sido creadas, entonces solo se añade la segunda palabra, pero si la segunda palabra ya existe en ese archivo entonces no se añade.

Ejemplo.

```
(Yo seré Lola.)
Yo.txt= soy seré
seré.txt= Lola.
Lola.txt=(no habrá nada aqui oración terminada)
```

Con esta función obtengo la primera palabra de la oración.

```
def primera_pal(oracion):
    for palabra in oracion.split():
        print("llege a la funcion: ",palabra)
        return palabra
```

Ignora esto

```
def procesar_parrafo(parrafo):

    completo = ' '.join(parrafo)
    #completo = completo.replace(",", ".")
    completo = completo.replace(";", ".")
    completo = completo.replace("—","")
    completo = completo.replace("«", "")
    completo = completo.replace("»", "")
    lista_punto = completo.split(".")

    return [x.strip() for x in lista_punto]
parrafo=[]
activar_af=0
with open(ruta_libros.format("quijote"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as libro:
    parrafo = []
    for line in libro:
        line = line.strip()  # Botar los whitespaces al final.
        if line == '':
            for oracion in procesar_parrafo(parrafo):
                #print(oracion)
                with open(ruta_libros.format("quijote2"), "a", encoding="utf-8") as librox:
```

Bien aquí se encuentra el invento (necesito añadir las oraciones en sus respectivos archivos, con salto de linea.)

```
                    ### ENFOCATE DE AQUI PARA ABAJO #####
                pal_en1=oracion
                pal_en2=pal_en1
                print("-----Pal 2 Antes: ",pal_en2)
                activar_af=0
                for oracionx in pal_en2.split():
                    #print("Oracionx: ", oracionx)

                    pr_pal = primera_pal(pal_en2)

                    #pr_pal=' '.join(pal_en2.split()[1:])
                    with open(ruta_conocimientos.format(pr_pal), "a", encoding="utf-8") as datox:
                        if oracionx not in "" and activar_af <=2:
                            print("La oracionx: ",oracionx)
                            print("Dentro-----------------------------------------")
                            print("primera_palabra: ",pr_pal)
                            datox.write(oracionx+" ")
                            pal_en2=pal_en2.replace(pr_pal,"",1)

                            activar_af+=1
                            if activar_af>=2:
                                datox.write("\n")
                                datox.close()
                            print("Pal 2 despues: ",pal_en2)
                        #if oracion not in "":
                    #    librox.write(oracion+".")

            parrafo = []
        else:
            #print(line)
            parrafo.append(line)
```

Comment: ¿Quieres 1 archivo por cada palabra de cada oración de la novela de Don Quijote? Eso es una cantidad bastante grande de archivos: *si contamos a partir de la parte que dice “En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme…” tiene 377.032 palabras*. No estoy muy seguro de lo que pretendes, pero suena a que necesitas con urgencia una base de datos. Saludos

Comment: Aún tomando el caso en que sea 1 archivo por cada palabra *diferente*, sería una gran cantidad de archivos igualmente, ya que la novela de Cervantes tiene casi 23 mil palabras diferentes. Puedo entender que esto funcione para algunos cientos de palabras, pero piensa que aunque desmenuces la novela de esta forma y dependiendo del sistema de archivos en el que almacenes los mismos, habrá un gran impacto en el desempeño / rendimiento de dicho sistema de archivos. Nuevamente pienso que necesitas con urgencia un sistema de base de datos. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola, Mauricio tambien he pensado en eso y decidí hacerlo de una forma menos pesada, he actualizado el código y he añadido la idea de lo que ahora quiero conseguir, pero tampoco he logrado mucho avance, solucione algunas cositas del viejo tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura de datos que quieres almacenar en el fondo es una lista de palabras (los ficheros) cada una de las cuales es una referencia a otra lista de palabras (los contenidos de los ficheros).

Creo que puedes almacenar de forma mucho más eficiente toda esa información si en Python creas un diccionario cuyas claves sean las palabras, y cuyos valores sean las listas con otras palabras.

Siguiendo tu mismo ejemplo, en lugar de crear ficheros llamados `Yo.txt`, `soy.txt`, `seré.txt`, `Lola..txt` que contengan palabras, lo que tendrías sería el siguiente diccionario:

```
diccionario = {
 "Yo": ["soy", "seré"],
 "soy": ["Lola."],
 "seré": ["Lola."],
 "Lola.": [],
}
```

Una vez hayas construido este diccionario en memoria (que será mucho más rápido que ir creando la estructura equivalente en disco), puedes guardarlo también en un fichero, si lo que te preocupa es la persistencia de los datos (es decir, que puedan seguir existiendo en disco una vez el programa ha terminado).

Grabarlo a fichero puede ser extremadamente simple si usas el módulo `pickle`:

```
import pickle

with open("vocabulario.data", "wb") as f:
  pickle.dump(diccionario, f)
```

Y para recuperarlo sería así:

```
with open("vocabulario.data", "rb") as f:
  diccionario = pickle.load(f)
```

El uso de `pickle` como ves es bastante simple. El inconveniente que tiene es que el fichero que resulta no es editable. Si lo abres con un editor de texto verás "basura" mezclada con tus datos (esa "basura" en realidad es la que dice a python de qué tipo son los datos allí almacenados lo que le permite luego recuperarlos).

Si prefieres un formato "editable" (aunque solo sea para leerlo desde un editor, sin necesidad de cargarlo en Python) puedes usar `json`. En este caso lo guardarías así:

```
import json

with open("vocabulario.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(diccionario, f)
```

Y lo recuperarías así:

```
import json

with open("vocabulario.json", "r") as f:
  diccionario = json.load(f)
```

Como ves la mecánica es prácticamente la misma, pero el contenido del fichero es ahora legible y de hecho parece un diccionario Python igual al que escribí más arriba (el formato JSON, aunque no es exactamente igual a la sintaxis de datos de Python, se le parece bastante en muchos casos, y en este caso particular en que los datos son todos de tipo cadena, lista y diccionario, la sintaxis sería idéntica).

### Nota

Ya que el cometido de todo esto es almacenar una estructura de datos que capture las parejas de palabras que pueden aparecer una a continuación de otra, creo que te hace falta algún tipo de marcador de "inicio de frase" y de "fin de frase", a modo de *pseudopalabras* adicionales. De este modo el marcador de inicio sería una clave más del diccionario y la lista asociada daría qué palabras pueden comenzar una oración. De igual modo, si una palabra puede ser la última de una oración, entre los elementos de su lista aparecería la marca de fin de frase.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que la marca de inicio es "START" y la de fin es "END" (cualquier otra cadena que no pueda aparecer como palabra serviría). Entonces el diccionario correspondiente a tu ejemplo sería más bien así:

```
diccionario = {
 "START": ["Yo"],
 "Yo": ["soy", "seré"],
 "soy": ["Lola."],
 "seré": ["Lola."],
 "Lola.": ["END"],
}
```

Esto permite saber por dónde empezar una frase, y también permitir que algunas palabras puedan aparecer tanto al final de la frase como seguidas de otras (si el marcador especial "END" aparece entre su lista de sucesoras).

## Bonus

Un diccionario como el anterior puede construirse con unas pocas líneas de código, suponiendo que la lista `oraciones` contiene una serie de frases, como por ejemplo:

```
oraciones = [
 'En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor',
 'Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos y quebrantos los sábados, lantejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda'
]
```

El código siguiente serviría para construir el diccionario buscado. Durante la construcción de ese diccionario uso conjuntos (`set()`) como una forma eficiente de evitar meter palabras repetidas en las listas. Al final del bucle convierto esos conjuntos en listas ordenadas alfabéticamente para que sean más fáciles de examinar:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

# Palabras especiales para marcar inicio y fin de frase
START = " START "
END = " END "

for linea in oraciones:
  anterior = START
  for palabra in linea.split():
    d[anterior].add(palabra)
    anterior = palabra
  d[anterior].add(END)

# Una vez procesado todo el libro, pasamos los conjuntos a listas ordenadas
d = {k: list(sorted(v)) for k,v in d.items() }
```

Como curiosidad, para las dos frases del Quijote antes mostradas, el diccionario resultante será:

```
{' START ': ['En', 'Una'],
 'En': ['un'],
 'Mancha,': ['de'],
 'Una': ['olla'],
 'acordarme,': ['no'],
 'adarga': ['antigua,'],
 'algo': ['más'],
 'algún': ['palomino'],
 'antigua,': ['rocín'],
 'astillero,': ['adarga'],
 'añadidura': ['los'],
 'carnero,': ['salpicón'],
 'consumían': ['las'],
 'corredor': [' END '],
 'cuyo': ['nombre'],
 'de': ['algo', 'añadidura', 'cuyo', 'la', 'lanza', 'los', 'su'],
 'domingos,': ['consumían'],
 'duelos': ['y'],
 'en': ['astillero,'],
 'flaco': ['y'],
 'galgo': ['corredor'],
 'ha': ['mucho'],
 'hacienda': [' END '],
 'hidalgo': ['de'],
 'la': ['Mancha,'],
 'lantejas': ['los'],
 'lanza': ['en'],
 'las': ['más', 'tres'],
 'los': ['de', 'domingos,', 'sábados,', 'viernes,'],
 'lugar': ['de'],
 'mucho': ['tiempo'],
 'más': ['noches,', 'vaca'],
 'no': ['ha', 'quiero'],
 'noches,': ['duelos'],
 'nombre': ['no'],
 'olla': ['de'],
 'palomino': ['de'],
 'partes': ['de'],
 'que': ['carnero,', 'vivía'],
 'quebrantos': ['los'],
 'quiero': ['acordarme,'],
 'rocín': ['flaco'],
 'salpicón': ['las'],
 'su': ['hacienda'],
 'sábados,': ['lantejas'],
 'tiempo': ['que'],
 'tres': ['partes'],
 'un': ['hidalgo', 'lugar'],
 'vaca': ['que'],
 'viernes,': ['algún'],
 'vivía': ['un'],
 'y': ['galgo', 'quebrantos']}
```

Comment: Nunca lo habría hecho mejor jaja, me gustaria entender esta parte d[anterior].add(palabra) ¿Que no tendria que a ver una condicional para que solo se guarde una vez la primera palabra? cual es la logica de esta parte?

Comment: Aaah ya entendi, oh eres un genio jajaja.

Comment: Hay un truco en el código que quizás debí explicar. Al crear `d` como un `defaultdict(set)` es un tipo especial de diccionario en el que puedes intentar acceder a una clave aunque no exista. `d["loquesea"]` no va a dar error, sino que va a crear esa clave y le va a poner como valor un conjunto vacío. Por eso puedo hacer directamente `d[anterior].add(palabra)` sin necesidad de mirar antes si `anterior` estaba en el diccionario. Si no estaba, se creará en ese momento un conjunto vacío (y se añadirá la palabra) si ya estaba, se añadirá la palabra.

Comment: Por otro lado, por ser conjuntos (set) las palabras repetidas se gestionan automáticamente, ya que un conjunto nunca almacena duplicados. Imagina tener que hacer esto con tus ficheros, tener que abrir cada uno y buscar en cada una de sus líneas si la palabra ya estaba para evitar volver a ponerla.